# How can I tell if a matrix is singular or nonsingular?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

When solving a problem about linearly independent/dependent, I don't know what the answer means.

Question: Determine whether the collection of vectors is linearly independent in $R^3$:
$(1,2,4)^T$ , $(2,1,3)^T$ , $(4,-1,1)^T$

Answer:
If $$c_1(1,2,4)^T+c_2(2,1,3)^T+c_3(4,-1,1)^T=(0,0,0)^T$$

Then,
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
c_1+2c_2+4c_3=0\\
2c_1+c_2-c_3=0\\
4c_1+3c_2+c_3=0\\
\end{array}$$
The coefficient matrix of the system is singular and hence the system has nontrivial solutions. Therefore the vectors are linearly dependent.

I know the method to determine whether the matrix is linearly independent or not by computing $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+...c_nv_n=0$, but here I don't know why the system is singular, so how can I tell whether it's singular or not? Are there any ways to know?

Comment: Pretty much the whole point of determinants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the determinant of the coefficient matrix is zero, then the matrix is singular and the system in dependent. The homogeneous system in this case has a non-zero solution as well as the trivial zero solution.

Otherwise the matrix is non-singular and the system has a unique solution which in case of homogeneous system is $(0,0,0)^T$

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches that can be take (some have already been provided). One other is to apply [Gaussian Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) so that the matrix is in [row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) (commonly denoted as $\operatorname{REF}(A)$).

If the $\operatorname{rank}\left(\operatorname{REF}(A)\right) \neq n$ then $A$ is not invertible and the system of equations is singular.